# Blade concatenate variables with default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is there a way to make something like this work?

```
{{ $user->name .' '. $user->last_name or '---' }}
```

Setting it up with @if-then isn't "elegant" as most of the laravel stuff is :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if `$user->name` and `$user->last_name` are not empty first, then determine what value you want to show with a shorthand if/else statement:

```
{{ ($user->name && $user->last_name) ? $user->name .' '. $user->last_name : '---' }}
```

Comment: That'll do, yes. I was just hoping there's an out-of-the-box blade version. Thnx!